# I have a flexbox with 2 columns, can I make the second column go under the first one under certain dimension?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

As you can see in the snippet, I have 2 columns, however, I want to make it so that the red column goes under the blue one ( and they both take 100% of the parent width ) when the browser becomes less than 1200px.

Now if I were using 2 inline-block elements I would just create a media query that would make both elements block, however, now that I'm trying to use flexbox, I'm not sure how to do this.

```css
.specific-image-container {
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
.specific-image-column {
    flex: 4;
    background-color: blue;
}
.more-images-column {
    flex: 1;
    background-color: red;
}
.content {
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="specific-image-container">

    <div class="specific-image-column">
        <div class='content'>s</div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="more-images-column">
        <div class='content'>s</div>
    </div>
    
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `flex-direction` to `column` within a media query

```
@media all and (max-width: 1200px) {
    .specific-image-container {
        flex-direction: column;
    }
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for :) , will select as answer in 7 minutes.

Comment: Just a small nit pick, but the query should be for 1199px since OP wants the layout to change when the screen is _less than_ 1200px.